# is that anyway for array to didnt back to [0] again and countinue it in last number?

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array which have 2 or more value , 
here my php :

```
for ($c = 0; $c < $jumpack; $c++) {
    $packinglist = $_POST['packinglist'][$c];


    $a= mysql_query("INSERT INTO packing_list VALUES('','$packinglist','$surat[id_surat]','$surat[no_surat_jalan]')");

 }
```

and here my html :

```
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
                {
    echo"
    <input class='form-control' type='text' id='jumrow' name='jumpack[]' value=''/> 
    ";
 for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
<input class='form-control sedang' type='text' id='packinglist_$i' name='packinglist[]'/>
}

    }
```

so i need to loop `jumpack[]`  and i need to loop `packinglist[]` too
thanks

Comment: You can use another var as counter. And when needed just increase the counter. Then whenever you want access the array using the counter as index.

Comment: You mean you want to know the amount of elements in the array? In that case you can use `count();`.

Comment: What is the value of $jumpack ?

Comment: please check my update

Comment: @Santy i have to input $jumpack value manually , cause its a textbox

Comment: very confusing *question*

Comment: yea im confuse too to explain , my english so bad

Comment: if i have 5 value of jumpack like "1 2 3 4 5" and  a loop will stop for each jumpack was i filled it .but i have 20 packing list value , when i use `$_POST['packinglist'][$c]` it will count array number of 
'[0][1]`,`[0][1][2]' and more , and i want `$c` count append how many $_post[packinglist] appearing

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you need to know the amount of fields posted?

```
$jumpacks = count($_POST['jumpack']);
$packinglists = count($_POST['packinglist']);
```

Now $jumpacks would be 5 and $packinglists would be 20 in your example.

Edit:
(trying to understand what you mean :)

```
foreach($_POST['jumpack'] as $jumpackvalue) {
    //this means we are going over each posted jumpack, there are 5 in your example, so on each run we get the value of the next one in $jumpackvalue.
    echo $jumpackvalue.'<br>'; //to test

    //you can do the same now with the packinglist inside this loop
    foreach($_POST['packinglist'] as $listvalue) {
        echo $listvalue.'<br>'; //to test
    }
}
```

Comment: if i have 5 value of jumpack like "1 2 3 4 5" and  a loop will stop for each jumpack was i filled it .but i have 100 packing list value (20 * 5) , when i use `$_POST['packinglist'][$c]` it will count array number of 
'[0][1]`,`[0][1][2]' and more , and i want `$c` count append how many $_post[packinglist] appearing and the index of array didnt back to [0] again

Comment: Oh, i see, you want all the packinglists for EACH jumpack?

Comment: yeah like that , but even i filled EACH jumpack by 20 , `$_POST[packinglist][$c]` index of `$c` back to [0] again